# Get rows that don't match rows in another table

Tags: sql

In SQL, how would I do something like a reverse join?

For example suppose I have the following two tables

```
UsedSlide
    SlideId
    UserId
    SomeOtherValue

LegacySlide
   SlideId
   UserId
```

How would I select all rows in `UsedSlide` where the `SlideId` and `UserId` don't match the values in any row of `LegacySlide`?

Note that I specifically made it two things we're matching on since otherwise I know that I can use `NOT IN` and a subselect.

**Bonus:** In my scenario the dataset is small, but what if it was large? How do I do it most efficiently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `not exists` operator:

```
SELECT *
FROM   UsedSlide u
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   LegacySlide l
                   WHERE  u.SlideId = l.SlideId AND u.UserId = l.UserId)
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking (also `SELECT 1` might be better).  But wouldn't this preform horribly on large datasets?

Comment: Acc. to his "bonus-question", `NOT EXISTS` is also the most efficient approach(with proper indexes). http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Comment: @GeorgeMauer: is also use `SELECT 1` but it's not more   efficient than `SELECT *`.

Comment: Oh ok, I assumed since you weren't projecting all rows it would be, but I guess the optimizer would handle it

Answer (score 2):

LEFT JOIN CAN BE USED

```
  SELECT * from
  UsedSlide US
  LEFT JOIN LegacySlide LS
  ON US.SlideId = LS.SlideId
  and US.UserId = LS.UserId
  WHERE LS.SlideId is NULL
  AND LS.UserId is NULL
```

Comment: That's pretty interesting...any idea on the performance of this versus `NOT EXISTS`? Also, shouldn't the `WHERE` clause test `ls`, not `us`?

Comment: In SQL server, with NOT EXISTS , seen some performance degradation for a large set of data. yes you are right need to check for LS, i will update

Comment: @georg: in the comment ito the other answer i had provided a link to an article that addesses this topic which explains why Not Exists can be more efficient than other approaches and has no issues with null values(like Join).

Answer (score 1):

Use the **EXCEPT** operator:

Some sample code I have tested:

```
CREATE TABLE #UsedSlide (SlideId INT NOT NULL, UserId INT NOT NULL, SomeOtherValue VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL)
CREATE TABLE #LegacySlide (SlideId INT NOT NULL, UserId INT NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO #UsedSlide(SlideId, UserId, SomeOtherValue)
VALUES
(1, 35, 'testing123'),
(2, 39, 'testingabc'),
(3, 24, 'testingxyz')

INSERT INTO #LegacySlide( SlideId, UserId )
VALUES  (1, 35),
        (2, 39)

SELECT SlideId, UserId
FROM #UsedSlide
EXCEPT
SELECT SlideId, UserId
FROM #LegacySlide
```

This produces the following result set:

```
SlideId UserId
------- ------
3       24
```

Note: the order of statements in the EXCEPT is important here.  If you ran that last statement as:

```
SELECT SlideId, UserId
FROM #LegacySlide
EXCEPT
SELECT SlideId, UserId
FROM #UsedSlide
```

...that would NOT produce the desired effect.  This is basically an operation on sets: find the "tuple" that is not in the set of tuples.

The companion operator to **EXCEPT** is **INTERSECT** - find tuples in common between two sets.  Both are very useful operators.

As an aside, I believe that Oracle has a **MINUS** operator that is roughly equivalent to EXCEPT (someone can verify and find the link?)

Comment: Can this be used to select *all* columns from `UsedSlide` though or do we need a join for that?

Comment: You **would** need to join back up with the original table again:       

    SELECT u.SlideId, u.UserId, SomeOtherValue
    FROM #UsedSlide u
    JOIN (
     SELECT SlideId, UserId
     FROM #UsedSlide
     EXCEPT
     SELECT SlideId, UserId
     FROM #LegacySlide
    ) m
    ON u.SlideId = m.SlideId AND u.UserId = m.UserId

Comment: @Rajesh, your approach is very viable, but performance can suffer for large datasets because of the IS NULL check.  Here is a good post which describes the poor performance of IS NULL: http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/do-you-use-column-param-or-param-is-null/